# Implementation of frama-clang

Tags: frama-c

So far I've found the STANCE project ([Stance project website](http://www.stance-project.eu)) a reader ([found on the website](http://www.stance-project.eu/media/publications/Euro_llvm_FramaC.pdf)) and a presentation ([also found on the website](http://www.stance-project.eu/media/publications/Frama-Clang_presentation_V_Prevosto__F_Vedrine.pdf)). Also, apparently there will be a frama-c day taking place on June 20th where frama-clang is going to be introduced.

However, I am wondering  whether there is an implementation to play around with frama-clang.

Answer (score 2):

Since a few minutes, there is: http://frama-c.com/frama-clang.html (don't forget to read the **Caveat** part). It is released as a new plug-in, under LGPL2.1. Frama-Clang is compatible with Frama-C Aluminium (i.e. the latest Frama-C version so far), and clang/llvm 3.8 (be sure to either use the dev packages of your distribution or compile clang by hand).